# Vue.compile fails for HTML element nesting greater than two

Tags: javascript, vue.js, compilation, runtime

Using Vue.compile for async HTML seems to have a maximum complexity of two elements deep. Anything higher throws `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"` upon rendering.

So `<section><p>hello</p><section>` works fine but `<section><p>hello <em>there</em></p><section>` fails.

Code example below and [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sjeiti/t99jxLrz/).
(async simulated by setTimeout)

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'simple template works',
    template: Vue.compile('<p>{{msg}}</p>').render
  },
  render(createElement) {
    return this.template();
  },
  mounted() {
    // below fails
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.template = Vue.compile('<div><p>{{msg}}</p><p>Nesting more than three tags deep <em>fails</em>?</p></div>').render;
    }, 1000);
    // below renders fine
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.template = Vue.compile('<div><p>{{msg}}</p><p>Nesting more than three tags deep fails?</p></div>').render;
    }, 2000);
  }
})
```

Can anybody tell what is going on here? Should 'complex' templates be compiled/rendered differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue.compile returns an object with *two* properties, both of which are required to properly render a component. The first property is `render` which is the root render function for the template, and the second is `staticRenderFns` which is a collection of functions created when the template is compiled that are used to optimize the render process. As you might surmise from the name, they render static content.

In some cases, as you found, where the compilation process doesn't generate any static render functions, your code might work without including it. But, generally, you will need both properties to render properly.

Here is an updated version of your code that works.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'simple template works',
    template: Vue.compile('<p>{{msg}}</p>')
  },
  render(createElement) {
    let msg = this.msg
    let base = {
      data(){
        return {
          msg
        }
      }
    }
    let component = Object.assign({}, this.template, base)
    return createElement(component);
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.template = Vue.compile('<div><p>{{msg}}</p><p>Nesting more than three tags deep <em>fails</em>?</p></div>');
    }, 1000);
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.template = Vue.compile('<div><p>{{msg}}</p><p>Nesting more than three tags deep fails?</p></div>');
    }, 2000);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Vue.compile is [documented here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile).

There is also a short bit of [documentation here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Template-Compilation).

Linus Borg, one of the core team for Vue, explains a little bit about staticRenderFns [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-compile-what-is-staticrenderfns-render-vs-staticrenderfns/3950/5):

> Well, static Render Functions are used to optimize the render process by essentially caching parts of the DOM tree that are static and therefore can’t change. When you call the render function that was generated along with them, it will call these functions to get those static parts.
>
> So there’s no sensible way to call or update them during runtime, they
> have to be present on the component as a prop with that name and will
> be called by the render function when needed.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere on vuejs.org? I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Sjeiti I updated the answer with some pointers to documentation.